# Consume Result of .NET Function Returning LIST(Of Type) in Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Imagine the following VB.NET class:

```
Public Class P
    Public Function GetDumbList() As List(Of DumbPeople)
        Dim retList As New List(Of DumbPeople)
        retList.Add Person1
        retList.Add Person2
        Return retList
    End Function
End Class
```

Now we have the following Classic ASP Page:

```
<%
Dim P
Set P = Server.CreateObject("Project.Assembly.Namespace.P")

retList = P.GetDumbList()
...
...
...
%>
```

How do you use retList?  I have tried looping through using the 2 following methods:

```
1. For Each Person in retList
```

Throws error "Object not a collection"

```
2. For i = 0 To Ubound(retList)
```

Throws error "Type mismatch: -UBound-

Thanks in advance for your help.
Jake

***UPDATE***

Based on help from Chris Haas we were able to solve the issue.  It does require a second ASPClassic helper function to convert the List(of T) to an Object array; however, COM objects cannot expose generic methods.  Because of this, the input must be a specific type of List to be converted to the Object array.  Solution Below

```
Public Function DumbPeopleListToObjectArray(ByVal DPList As IList(Of DumbPeople)) As Object()
    Return Array.ConvertAll(Of DumbPeople, Object)(DPList.ToArray(), New Converter(Of DumbPeople, Object)(Function(j) DirectCast(j, Object)))
End Function
```

Thank you to Chris Haas for putting me on the right direction.
Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to use generics with ASP Classic, I think you're going to need to convert it to an array. You could write a utility method for ASP Classic usage that takes a `IList(Of T)` and returns an `Object()`. Its an extra step for ASP Classic people to jump through but not the end of the world.

**EDIT**

Something like this might do the trick:

```
Public Shared Function ToASPClassicArray(Of T)(ByVal myList As IList(Of T)) As T()
    Return myList.ToArray()
End Function
```

**EDIT 2**

Here's another version that returns just an object, pretty ugly but should still work.

```
Public Shared Function ToASPClassicArray(Of T)(ByVal myList As IList(Of T)) As Object()
    Return Array.ConvertAll(Of T, Object)(myList.ToArray(), New Converter(Of T, Object)(Function(j) DirectCast(j, Object)))
End Function
```

Comment: And this utility method would be a .NET function or a classic ASP function?

Comment: Ill give this a shot and let you know.  Thanks for the help Chris!

Comment: Chris: What would the function footprint look like? `Public Function PersonToObject(ByVal PersonList As IList(Of Person)) As Object`?  Would the output be a list or a single record?

Comment: Getting an error: `Generic methods cannot be exposed to COM`.  Any ideas?

Comment: I created a type specific conversion `Public Function ToServicesArray(ByVal myList As IList(Of Service)) As Service()
    Return myList.ToArray()
End Function`  I can call this and call Ubound() on the return; however, i cannot pull any particular property from the return array like `Response.Write ServiceArray(i)("ServiceID")`