# Calling a .NET Function that requires a .NET type from Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

Please Help me.I am trying to over come this paoblem from last 2 days But i am not able to overcome.

I was able to set up the environment so that I can call .NET method (via COM) from a classic ASP page.

Everything actually works as intended until when I have to call a .NET method that requires a .NET type.

So I have a method named SetTable Like Below

I have a function like this in .Net

```
Public Sub SetTable(ByVal _City As City, ByVal _Country As Country)
          'doing some thing
End Sub
```

and i have asp code like this:

```
dim CountryUtil, City, Country
set CountryUtil= Server.CreateObject("mydll.CountryUtil")
set City= Server.CreateObject("mydll.City")
set Country = Server.CreateObject("mydll.Country")
city.id= 123
city.property = "so and so"

Country.id= 123
Country.property = "so and so"

CountryUtil.SetTable(City, Country)
```

' I get this error here:

'Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005' 'Invalid procedure call or argument: 'SetTable'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm struggling to find a reason that this would be considered a good programming practice.

Comment: @ulluoink has the best solution - you cannot do what you want in classic asp because every variable is a variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in vbscript you only have variants so Country and City are just objects of type variant not of type Country or City.

you will have to change the .net method SetTable (or write a new one) which accepts "variants" (object) and then cast those objects to your .net City and Country objects.

Comment: I tried this it is working for me I have changed function Like this

Comment: I tried this it is working for me I have changed function Like this Public Sub SetTable(ByVal _City As object,ByVal _Country As Object)
          'here i casted the objects in to classes
End Sub but i dont want function signature like above.Please How can i do it by using same signature (like: ByVal _City As object,ByVal _Country As Object)

Comment: @Avinash i'm not sure if i get your problem but couldn't you just write a new method like Public Sub SetTableFromASP(ByVal _City as object, ByVal _Country As Object) 'cast objects to your .net city and country then call (original) method SetTable(castedCity, castedCountry)

Comment: Thanks ulluoink. That is a nice solution but do we have any other solution? My client wont accept to this that is the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684495/consume-result-of-net-function-returning-listof-type-in-classic-asp

Answer (score 0):

My vbscript is a bit rusty, but don't you need to write this instead (without parens)?

```
CountryUtil.SetTable City, Country
```

Comment: Ya i tried this but it was not worked for me still it is giving error like above "Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005' 'Invalid procedure call or argument: 'SetTable'"

Comment: This parens shouldn't make any difference in this instance as the `SetTable` declaration is `ByVal` anyway.